# apache.commons.logging.log performance without debug logging code guard

Tags: java, log4j

[apache.coomons.logging.Log.Log2JLogger](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.html) provides code guards such as `log.IsDebugEnabled()`.   However, one can just go ahead and call `log.debug(message)`
and we do not see these messages if debug level is not configured.

From a performance perspective, especially considering we want to leave these debug messages for production debugging, would it be considered best practice to call these code guards before attempting to log?

For example, would this be considered best practice?

```
if log.isDebugEnabled()
     log.debug("trouble brewing...");
```

Or does calling

```
log.debug("I'll slow you down...");
```

already do this for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cost of creating your parameter to the logging method is high, then you should call the guard method first. In the example you gave, there is no point since a static String has no performance cost and as you correctly surmise, the logging framework makes the check anyway before deciding whether to log.

But consider the following;

```
logger.debug(myObject.someMethod());
```

In this case, the `myObject.someMethod()` will be called *prior* to the logger receiving the return value from it. If that method performs lengthy operations, then you will suffer the performance penalty whether the logger is enabled for debug or not. In this case, you **would** want to use the `isDebugEnabled()` prior to making that call.